# Microsoft Teams AdaptiveCard message can not display the image from Sharepoint

Tags: image, sharepoint, message

I send a AdaptiveCard message with images stored on SharePoint by Power Automate, but the Teams App was unable to display the images and the Teams Web was able to display them normally.What should I do to display images correctly on the new version of Teams App?

Due to organizational requirements, it is not possible to set image permissions to anonymous access

The Adaptive Card Json:
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.4",
"action": "type",
"actions": [
{
"type": "Action.OpenUrl",
"title": "https://www.microsoft.com",
"url": "https://www.microsoft.com",
"style": "positive"
}
],
"body": [
{
"type": "Image",
"url": "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/:i:/r/sites/xxxxx",
"size": "Large"
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Hero Card",
"wrap": true,
"size": "Medium"
},
{
"type": "TextBlock",
"text": "Subtitle",
"wrap": true,
"size": "Small"
}
]
}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu1dg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oVa4.png)